# Не работает ЧПУ(и стандартный и SeoPro) - opencart(2.3)

Tags: opencart, чпу

Нужна помощь по настройке ЧПУ, при отключенном все нормально, но как только включаешь, появляется ошибка, что страница не найдена
Манипуляции с htaccess проводил, не помогло ни одно решение найденное на форуме.
С чем может быть связанна проблема?

Сервер Apache/2.2.29 (Gentoo) mod_dp/0.99.7 PHP/7.1.26
После включения чпу, падает в 404
Текущий htaccess:

```html
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
# Require all denied
## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Comment: Укажите ваш сервер, какие манипуляции и в каком виде сейчас .htaccess, как настраиваете чпу

Comment: Обновил в посте

Comment: проверьте .htaccess, напишите каких-нибудь кракозябр в любом месте в отдельной строчке, очистите кеши и перезагрузите сайт. Если с htaccess всё норм, то сайт упадёт с 500й.

Comment: Хм, падает только если в первой строчке писать, в любом другом месте не реагирует

Comment: А от чего может зависеть работоспособность чпу, помимо htaccess?

Comment: буквально на всякий случай проверьте кодировку .htaccess. он должен быть utf-8.

Comment: проверил, да в utf-8, да и если бы нет, думаю сайт в 500 был бы

Comment: Имеете доступ к логам? Посмотрите их. Может там что-то есть, наводящее